# Why can't I set the currentPreviewItemIndex in qlpreviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook

I've been working on a project using QuickLook Framework. I used tableview to show the files and used quicklook preview to show them. I created a QLPreviewController in the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath and tried to set the currentPreviewItemIndex with the indexPath.row to show the file I choose. Codes like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // When user taps a row, create the preview controller
    QLPreviewController *previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

    // Set data source
    [previewer setDataSource:self];

    // Which item to preview
    [previewer setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Tapped Row: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] stringValue]);
    NSLog(@"The INDEX: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithInt:previewer.currentPreviewItemIndex] stringValue]);

    // Push new viewcontroller, previewing the document
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewer animated:YES];
}
```

But the result is that it shows the same file (the first one in filelist) no matter which cell I choose in the tableview. The "Tapped Row:" in log shows the right index **but "The INDEX:" is always -1**, which seems I failed to set currentPreviewItemIndex.

What is wrong with this? How can I set the index properly?